# Cannot find the Xpath - Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have been trying to scrape data from google analytics. This is what the code looks like:

```py
driver.implicitly_wait(40)
user_ids = []
for i in range(1, 9):
    user_id = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="ID-explorer-table-dataTable-key-0-{i}"]/div'
    )
    user_ids.append(user_id.text)
```

I encountered the following error:
**selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ID-explorer-table-dataTable-key-0-1"]/div"}**

Although this xpath is present on the page, selenium still throws this error. I have also done `driver.implicitly_wait(40)` to wait for the site to open but it still throws me the same error.

After going through a couple of stackoverflow links, I tried using `WebDriverWait` and also tried `time.sleep` instead of `implicitly_wait` but I still get the same error.

Here's the HTML Snippet:

```
<td class="ID-dimension-data-0 _GAwr">
    <span class="_GApu ">
        <div id="ID-explorer-table-dataTable-key-0-0">
            <div class="C_USER_LIST_TEXT_DIV _GASu ACTION-nav TARGET-visitors-user-activity">1591561263.1662756787</div>
        </div>
    </span>
</td>
```

I basically want the value 1591561263.1662756787

Comment: Have you verified that the xpath is available *in the HTML fetched by selenium*? Sometimes this will be different from what you see in your browser.

Comment: yep! @larsks I have.

Comment: please share the URL or HTML snippet if it's possible

Comment: Include the HTML as text in the question so that we can copy and paste it.

Comment: Sometimes i got this error when element was in some structure (frame or some other). And so i use driver.switch_to.[frame, window, ..]

Comment: HTML text has been added

Comment: well, you can try debugging by checking if you're able to locate the outer tags of the target web element.  it's difficult to guess the actual cause of the error unless we get to see the complete HTML snippet.

Comment: As I said, I am not able to locate any other tags on that website, it throws me the same error.

Comment: In your code you are using `range(1, 9)` but the HTML provided is '0'. Are you sure that '1' exists on the page? A URL to the page would help immensely.

Comment: You can't access that page so even if I share the URL it won't be of any help @JeffC

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code.

```
user_ids = []

# try locating those elements which contains "ID-explorer-table-dataTable"
visitors = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//table[@id='ID-rowTable']//div[contains(@id,'ID-explorer-table')]")

#Iterate over to find the internal element which has the Visitors ID
for visitor in visitors:
    user_id = visitor.find_element(By.XPATH,"./div").text
    print(user_id)
    user_ids.append(user_id)
```

Make sure that the element you are trying to find and extract data from, is not inside a `iframe` or a `shadow-root`.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the index from your locator. That will get you all elements that exist, no matter the index. This will also be faster because it will get all elements in one find instead of hitting the page for each index. Then you loop through all retrieved elements and store the `.text`. Remove all instances of implicit wait and use the added `WebDriverWait`.

```
user_ids = []
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
ids = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR('[id^="ID-explorer-table-dataTable-key-0-"] > div')))
for id in ids:
    user_ids.append(id.text)
```